# Get Registered Custom Post Type to get All Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get all the Custom Post Types Registered either by theme or plugin, but no method is working.

```
$postargs = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false
);

$postoutput = 'names';
$postoperator = 'and';    
$post_types = get_post_types( $postargs, 'names', 'and' ); 
/// Main Loop Start
foreach ($post_types as $post_type){  
//and then i want to Get all the Custom Taxonomies for those post types in a loop
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('$post_type', 'objects');    
// Loop 
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
// Do Stuff with taxonomy
}    // Loop




    }    /// Main Loop Ends
```

**But the problem is only WordPress Defaults Post Types are showing up if i do**

```
'_builtin' => true
```

- post
- page
- attachment

attachment

This is the Code to Registered Post Type
I don't get any post type, i currently have 8 Custom Post Types in the theme. the post is registered with this code...

```
$args = array(            
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Faq', 'yit' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Faq', 'yit' ),
                'plural_name' => __( 'Faqs', 'yit' ),
                'item_name_sing' => __( 'Faq', 'yit' ),
                'item_name_plur' => __( 'Faqs', 'yit' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Faq', 'yit' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Faq', 'yit' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'yit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Faq', 'yit' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Faq', 'yit' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Faq', 'yit' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Faq', 'yit' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Faqs', 'yit' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No Faqs', 'yit' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Faqs in the Trash', 'yit' ),
            ),            
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'public' => true,
            //'menu_position' => 30,
            //'icon_menu' => ,
            'has_archive' => 'faq',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => apply_filters( 'yit_faqs_rewrite', 'faq' ) ),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'cats'),
            'description' => "Faq"

        );
        register_post_type('faq', $args);
```

Comment: Are you sure the custom post types are properly registered? Are they public? What do you get if you just use `get_post_types()` with no arguments?

Comment: Yes, i tried woocommerce plugin which adds custom post types, i tried few themes which have custom post types, still same results. only above 3 post type show up if i do '_builtin' => true

Comment: You should be setting `'_builtin' => false` otherwise you will only be showing the built in post types (Quote Codex: If `true`, will return WordPress default post types. Use `false` to return only custom post types.)

Comment: I would register your FAQ post type on the init hook. When are you attempting to query the post types? Any time after init should be fine. I would suggest you disable all plugins until you sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the problem was var_dump was executed before wordpress gets to any registered post type. so i added 199 in its priority and it worked. :)
Thank you all for your help...

```
function test(){
var_dump( get_post_types(array('_builtin' => false)));
}
add_action ('admin_init','test', 199);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested) code below. I believe the issue was the passing of the `$post_type` parameter to `get_object_taxonomies` (i.e. you passed it in quotes as `'$post_type'`. If uncomment the two `var_dump`'s you'll see what information is outputted.

```
<?php
    $postargs = array(
       'public'   => true,
       '_builtin' => false
    );

    $post_types = get_post_types( $postargs, 'names', 'and' ); 

    // Main Loop Start
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type){  
        //var_dump($post_type); 
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type, 'objects');    
        foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
                //var_dump($taxonomy);

                // Do Stuff with taxonomy here


            }//foreach taxonomy
    }//foreach post_type
?>
```

*Note: I've tested this with custom post types registered by a theme, but not with custom post types registered by plugins, but this should work for those too*

Comment: Please check the modified Answer, i still don't get the Custom Post Types. Currently nothing show up unlit i do builtin true.

Comment: What do you get if you do `$post_types = get_post_types(); var_dump($post_types);`?

Comment: Nothing,, its all empty...

Comment: What do you get if you try the codex example to [output a list of all public custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types#Output_a_list_of_all_public_custom_post_types)? If that shows up null you'll need to check your theme/plugin post types are created correctly

Comment: yes it shows null, tried it with official woocommerce plugin, but nothing show up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is not by using the `get_post_types` function, but where we call this function. I'll describe it, clearly.

Create a function:

```
function get_all_custom_post_types() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );
    $output = 'objects'; //'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
    $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    $custom_post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );           
    $post_types = array();
    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $k => $post_type ) {
        $post_types = $post_type;
    }           
    return $post_types ;
}
```

Use this custom function where you want to call this, but use only in any WordPress action or filter callback function, e.g. when creating a callback function for `add_metabox` action, then call this function:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_mb_option' );
function add_mb_option() {  
    add_meta_box( 'mb-option', 'custom metabox detail', 'add_mb_option_element',
        'custom_metabox', 'normal', 'high' );
}
function add_mb_option_element() {
    $cpts = get_all_custom_post_types();
    // More custom code will go here
}
```

Very simple to use.